# Capture the event while moving the mail from subfolder to inbox

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have the requirement to capture the event when the mail is moved from Subfolder to Inbox

The folder structure is as below

```
myarchive-mailbox name
Inbox Main folder
  requests Sub folder

myarchive
   Inbox
      requests
```

When the email is moved from requests subfolder to Inbox, of myarchive mailbox Name ,this mailbox item should be captured and the event handler should be invoked.

I have already implemented the code for capturing the event when the file is moved from myarchive inbox to requests.The code I have written is as below

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Events

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNs As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set olApp =Outlook.Application
    Set objNS =olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("myarchive")
    Set objFolder=objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
    Set Items=objFolder. Folders("requests").Items 
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemsAdd(ByVal item As Object)
  MsgBox "You moved the mail to requests folder"
End Sub
```

Comment: The line `Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Events` doesn't work in my version of Outlook (2010).

Comment: Which Inbox? Default Inbox or myarchive Inbox?

Comment: Its to myarchive Inbox.The event while moving from myarchive inbox to requests and then from requests to myarchive inbox should be captured.The code below works fine and thanks a lot, Om3r :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

The `Folder` object has a `BeforeItemMove` event.  In the ThisOutlookSession module, declare a folder object `WithEvents` to expose its events.

```
Private WithEvents mArchReqs As Folder

Public Property Set ArchReqs(olFldr As Folder)
    Set mArchReqs = olFldr
End Property

Public Property Get ArchReqs() As Folder
    Set ArchReqs = mArchReqs
End Property
```

Next you have set the folder you want to watch. Here I set the folder when the application starts up.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Set Me.ArchReqs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("requests")

End Sub
```

Finally, you can write the `BeforeItemMove` event procedure.

```
Private Sub mArchReqs_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)

    Debug.Print Item.Subject
    Debug.Print MoveTo.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dick !!

Comment: Hi Dick,I have now added the code which i implemented earlier for capturing event from inbox to myarchive subfolder.I used the BeforeItemMove Subroutine in my code and i am not successful in integrating the  BeforeItemMove Subroutine.Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are moving it to main Default Inbox, Then try the following code

```
Dim WithEvents SubFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set SubFolder = olNs.Folders("myarchive").Folders("Inbox").Folders("requests")                                                
    Set Inbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
End Sub

Private Sub SubFolder_BeforeItemMove(ByVal Item As Object, ByVal MoveTo As MAPIFolder, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MoveTo = Inbox Then
        MsgBox Item.Subject & " was moved to Inbox"
    End If

End Sub
```

Else change this line

```
Set Inbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

To This

```
Set Inbox = olNs.Folders("myarchive").Folders("Inbox")
```

*[Folder.BeforeItemMove Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869445.aspx)*