# How to detect when an email is moved among a particular set of folders?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I send a response to the sender when email is dragged into one of several monitored folders.

I use [ItemAdd Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook) for each monitored folder, which execute when an item (in my case an email) is added to it. The program extracts the subject line and sender's email address, then sends a response.

When an email is initially misclassified and dragged into the wrong monitored folder. My program needs to be able to issue a correction email to the sender whose email was misclassified.

My program needs to know when an email is dragged from a **monitored folder** to another **monitored folder** as opposed to the typical case when an email is dragged from the inbox.

### Idea 1:

[ItemRemove Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-itemremove-event-outlook) execute when an item is removed from a folder. Unlike ItemAdd Events, it doesn't pass the item removed as a parameter.
My idea was store the most recent item which was removed, then compare it to the item that was added to another monitored folder when an ItemAdd Event is executed.
If the two items are the same, it means the email was dragged directly from one to the other.
The lack of an Item parameter with the ItemRemoved event makes it impossible to obtain the email which was removed.

### Idea 2

Set a flag on execution of the ItemRemoved Events and evaluate on execution of the ItemAdd Events.
If the flag is set when ItemAdd is run, the program will know an item was just removed from a monitored folder and added to another monitored folder.
However, if an item is dragged directly from a folder with an ItemRemoved Event to a folder with an ItemAdd Event, *only the ItemAdd Event for the destination folder is executed*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682134/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using UserProperties? You can set a custom user property value to be the folder it's being added to, but also to watch the property to see if it's being moved to a new (monitored) folder. Here's an example:

```
Sub check_last_monitored_folder(myItem As Object, newFolderName As String)

    Dim prop As UserProperty
    Set prop = myItem.UserProperties.Find("LastMonitoredFolder")

    If prop Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Added to " & newFolderName & " folder"
        Set prop = myItem.UserProperties.Add("LastMonitoredFolder", olCombination)
        prop.Value = newFolderName
    Else
        Debug.Print "Moved from " & prop.Value & " folder to " & newFolderName
        prop.Value = newFolderName
    End If

End Sub
```